# ffmpeg start_time is negative

Tags: video, terminal, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to segment a video by start/end times.  For example, I have a set of time [[0,2],[2,4],[4,6]], and I'd call ffmpeg 3 times here to create the three 2 second videos at times 0, 2, and 4.

My problem is that these times (which are correct) are not correctly segmenting the video.  When I inspect the stats of the video with `ffprobe -i test.mov -show_format`, I noticed `start_time=-0.381044`.  I also know that this seems to be caused by trimming a video in QuickTime to produce this video.  In order to correct this, I must add (start + 0.381044) somewhere in my code, and the output is fine.

So, why is the start_time set to a negative value by the quicktime trimming?  How can I set start_time=0, so my code can work without the + 0.381044?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Video streams are usually inter-coded i.e. most frames rely on other frames to be decoded. So, when such a stream is trimmed, without transcoding, those reference frames, even if not within the trimmed time range, have to be included in the output in order for the video to be playable. Now, the trimming s/w can handle the timestamps of those reference frames in two ways: Assign them a negative PTS, so that they are available for decoding, but not displayed. Or start all timestamps from zero (or any positive value), so that they are displayed as well. In which case, the video trim isn't precise and includes extra frames.

If the main video were trimmed with FFmpeg, you can force the 2nd behaviour by adding `-avoid_negative_ts make_zero` to the trim command. But don't know how to set that using QT.

Comment: interesting.  so basically if i have frames 1-15 and 12-15 are ref frames than   the output video might start at -3?  

also, i'm still getting a negative start time when using ffmpeg for my trimmer with this command ffmpeg -i longerTest.mp4 -ss 0 -t 10 test2.mov -avoid_negative_ts make_zero

Comment: Option placement matters. The output filename should be at the end.

Comment: I now have the command ffmpeg -i longerTest.mp4 -ss 0 -t 10 -avoid_negative_ts make_zero test2.mov.  However, the start time is 0.042993.  I tried adding those options to the front of the command and this resulted in a 0 start_time but also seems to have corrupted the video.

Comment: The `avoid..` option is only if you're using ffmpeg in place of QT to trim the original video. Why don't you run the trims on the original video with `ffmpeg -ss START -t TIME -i orig.mov -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero trimmed.mov`. If you remove `-c copy`, you can remove the `avoid..` as well.

Comment: i switched to ffmpeg after you told me.  but the command [[[ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 10 -i longerTest.mp4 -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero test2.mov]]] results in a 0.32993 start time.

Comment: Run this first: `ffmpeg -i orig.mov -c copy -avoid_negative_ts make_zero zerostart.mov` and then trim the output.

Comment: In any case, check whether the trims are OK. Forget the start time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130076/discussion-between-alex-bollbach-and-mulvya).

Comment: well this explains why i was able to step back a frame before 0 in a video player when i tried to trim one frame off the start of my video!