# In python cv2, trying to use VideoCapture with a video that starts on a negative timestamp, won't fetch frames at the negative timestamp?

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, opencv, python

In python, if i get a video (that was clipped in way that shows a negative timestamp in a video player) (see example of problem here [ffmpeg start_time is negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41032079/ffmpeg-start-time-is-negative))

when trying to read that video through python opencv, I don't know how to get the frames starting from the negative timestamp. Instead what happens is first frame is the one at 0:00 timestamp, and when a video is read, a couple of frames get skipped at the beginning.
Code sample:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("video_with_negative_timestamp.mp4")
print(int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES))) # == 0
print(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)) # == 0.0, this is wrong, should be a negative value?
ret, frame = cap.read() # frame is not the first frame in the video.
```

Comment: Two questions: **1.** Can you post an mp4 file with negative timestamps for testing, or better: post FFmpeg command that builds synthetic video with negative timestamps? **2.** What happens when you try to re-encode the video with `-avoid_negative_ts make_zero` argument using FFmpeg command line? re-encode to new video file, or to PNG images, for example: `ffmpeg -i video_with_negative_timestamp.mp4 -avoid_negative_ts make_zero img%06d.png` ?

Comment: 1. I got the command from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video)  `ffmpeg -i test_video.mp4 -ss 60 -t 60 -acodec copy -vcodec copy video_with_negative_timestamp.mp4` may require some trial and error as you may get lucky on a keyframe

2, Attempting that option for video_with_negative_timestamp.mp4 removes the negative frames, losing those frames.

Comment: I also tried pyav via [this link](https://gist.github.com/Eugeny/5e1d496b5b01ea5be0d6ddb631d7702e), but that did not work either. Negative frames were skipped.

Comment: Looks like on some videos I'm able to get first frame on others I'm not. Not sure how to differentiate